# GoLang. I want to check the string for its contents for a criteria. How to do it in GoLang efficiently in terms of speed?

Tags: string, go

The string will only contain 0's or 4's. The string will start with 4. example: 444, 44, 40, 4400, 4440, etc. These all are valid strings but 404 is not valid.
Currently, I am checking if 4 is present immediately after 0. I am not sure that this one is efficient one.

Comment: Show us your attempt! *Efficient* in term of what? Less number of code, memory usage, speed, or?

Comment: To be clear, valid strings are 4's followed by 0's? Must it start with at least one 4?

Comment: @icza Yes, string must start with 4. Also, 4's followed by 0's is valid but not vice versa.

Comment: Is `4044` or `4040` valid or not? Or only the string `404` (no more/less) is invalid?

Comment: @yogesh_desai: "I am not sure that this one is efficient one." Then run Go benchmarks. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean leading `4` and following `0`.

## use regexp

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
)

func check(s string) bool {
    return regexp.MustCompile(`^4+0*$`).MatchString(s)
}

func main() {
    for _, tt := range []string{"444", "44", "40", "4400", "4440"} {
        if !check(tt) {
            panic("want true: " + tt)
        }
    }
    for _, tt := range []string{"404", "040"} {
        if check(tt) {
            panic("want false: " + tt)
        }
    }
}
```

## non-regexp

```
package main

func check(s string) bool {
    i := 0
    r := []rune(s)
    for i = 0; i < len(r); i++ {
        if r[i] != '4' {
            break
        }
    }
    if i == 0 {
        return false
    }
    for ; i < len(r); i++ {
        if r[i] != '0' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    for _, tt := range []string{"444", "44", "40", "4400", "4440"} {
        if !check(tt) {
            panic("want true: " + tt)
        }
    }
    for _, tt := range []string{"404", "040"} {
        if check(tt) {
            panic("want false: " + tt)
        }
    }
}
```

### faster version

```
func check(s string) bool {
    i, l := 0, len(s)
    for ; i < l; i++ {
        if s[i] != '4' {
            break
        }
    }
    if i == 0 {
        return false
    }
    for ; i < l; i++ {
        if s[i] != '0' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to look for the negative outcome `04`? A string/byte search function, no regular expressions.

Comment: Nothing is technically wrong, just much more expensive than it might be.

Comment: @mattn Is your approach more efficient than mine? I am just checking 4 after 0 in a for loop. Not using regexp

Comment: @zerkms +1 I am also thinking the same thing.

Comment: you should check `4` exists at least. :)

Comment: @yogesh_desai And how would we know what you do since you haven't posted your code? Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func isFourZero(s string) bool {
    i := 0
    var four bool
    for ; i < len(s) && s[i] == '4'; i++ {
        four = true
    }
    if four {
        if i >= len(s) {
            return true
        }
        var zero bool
        for ; i < len(s) && s[i] == '0'; i++ {
            zero = true
        }
        if zero {
            if i >= len(s) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    tests := []struct{ s string }{
        {"444"}, {"44"}, {"40"}, {"4400"}, {"4440"}, {"404"}, {"004"},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("%q \t %t\n", test.s, isFourZero(test.s))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"444"    true
"44"     true
"40"     true
"4400"   true
"4440"   true
"404"    false
"004"    false
```

---

Since we care about speed, let's look at some benchmarks:

```
BenchmarkIsFourZeroPeterSO-4        10000000           201 ns/op
BenchmarkValidateYogeshDesai-4       5000000           347 ns/op
BenchmarkCheckMattn-4                2000000           602 ns/op
```

`fourzero_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

var tests = []struct{ s string }{
    {"444"}, {"44"}, {"40"}, {"4400"}, {"4440"}, {"404"}, {"004"},
}

func BenchmarkIsFourZeroPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range tests {
            isFourZero(test.s)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkValidateYogeshDesai(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range tests {
            validate(test.s)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkCheckMattn(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range tests {
            check(test.s)
        }
    }
}

func isFourZero(s string) bool {
    i := 0
    var four bool
    for ; i < len(s) && s[i] == '4'; i++ {
        four = true
    }
    if four {
        if i >= len(s) {
            return true
        }
        var zero bool
        for ; i < len(s) && s[i] == '0'; i++ {
            zero = true
        }
        if zero {
            if i >= len(s) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func validate(str string) bool {
    if strings.HasPrefix(str, "4") {
        for i := 0; i < len(str)-1; i++ {
            if (str[i] == '0') && (str[i+1] == '4') {
                return false
            }
        }

    } else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func check(s string) bool {
    i := 0
    r := []rune(s)
    for i = 0; i < len(r); i++ {
        if r[i] != '4' {
            break
        }
    }
    if i == 0 {
        return false
    }
    for ; i < len(r); i++ {
        if r[i] != '0' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @peterSO +1 Thank you for this one. It proves that what I wanted. Thank you everyone. Cheers :)

Comment: Also, please point me to learn the bench marking stuff. I am a newbie for GoLang. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

**No RegExp**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
       )
func validate(str string) bool {

if strings.HasPrefix(str, "4") {
    for i:= 0; i < len(str)-1; i++ {
        if (str[i] == '0') && (str[i+1] == '4') {
            return false
        }
    }

}else { return false }

return true
}

func main() {

data := []string{"4", "44", "4400", "4440", "404", "004"}
      for _, val := range data {
            fmt.Println(validate(val))
      }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: your loop can starte from 1.

Comment: @mattn -1  The string will have only 4's and 0's. As I have already mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following is another implementation using only a single loop:

```
func yetAnotherValidation(s string) bool {
    //INVALID: if empty OR not started with '4'
    if len(s) == 0 || s[0] != '4' {
        return false
    }

    //INVALID: if len(s) > 2 AND contains "404"
    for k := 2; k < len(s); k++ {
        if s[k] == '4' && s[k-1] == '0' && s[k-2] == '4' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**Note**:

1. *`404`* (e.g. `404`, `4404`, `4040`, ...) is *INVALID*.
2. If `s` contains a character other than `0` or `4`, the result will be undefined (depending on the position of that character). If you need to ensure whether the input only contains `0` or `4`, then:

   ```
   func yetAnotherValidation2(s string) bool {
       //INVALID: if empty OR not started with '4'
       if len(s) == 0 || s[0] != '4' {
           return false
       }

       //INVALID: if second digit is not 0 or 4
       if len(s) > 1 && s[1] != '0' && s[1] != '4' {
           return false
       }

       //For len(s) > 2
       for k := 2; k < len(s); k++ {
           if s[k] == '4' && s[k-1] == '0' && s[k-2] == '4' {
               return false
           } else if s[k] != '0' && s[k] != '4' {
               //Neither 0 nor 4
               return false
           }
       }
       return true
   }
   ```

**UPDATE:**
Test and benchmark result:

```
=== RUN   TestValidate
444 true
44 true
40 true
4400 true
4440 true
404 false
004 false
--- PASS: TestValidate (0.00s)

BenchmarkYetAnotherValidation-4         50000000                38.5 ns/op
BenchmarkYetAnotherValidation2-4        30000000                45.6 ns/op
BenchmarkIsFourZero-4                   20000000                54.5 ns/op
BenchmarkCheckMattn-4                   10000000               144 ns/op
BenchmarkCheckMattnFast-4               30000000                50.2 ns/op
```